# How do I get the tab completion of a sublime text completion snipped to end inside the snippet?

Tags: sublimetext

One of my largest frustrations with Sublime Text 2 is that the 'table' shortcut always ends outside of the table block. For example, I type 'table' in an HTML filetype and it creates the following:

```
<table></table>
```

This places my cursor in the middle initially. If I then type 'tr' and click tab to create a `<tr></tr>` block, it places the text 'tr' inside the table tag, then goes to the outside of the 'table' block. I want the completion to end inside the 'table' block so I can do continuous code completions.

How can I modify the completion code to make it end inside the block? Here's the code from HTML.snippet-completions:

```
{ "trigger": "table", "contents": "<table>$1</table>" },
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

Just change the `$1` to `$0` !